# How to distrubute tasks to Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a database table called jobs and some producer service inserting data to this table. I need to create a consumer service to process this data.

I got a server with 8 core 16 threads and I create a thread pool with 16 threads.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
```

I will fetch 16 records from database and distrubute this data to consumer threads. After all threads completes their job I will fetch another 16 records.(I really don't know my solution is efficient or not)

How can I distrubute these tasks to consumer threads? Do I need to use BlockingQueue?

Comment: You can use a fork join pool instead of going with a fixed size thread pool

Comment: @NareshJoshi - it won't help.  The default fork-join thread pool is fixed sized, and this isn't a divide and conquer problem.

Comment: Yep a fork join wont help. ExecutorService should be apt for this . You could have a Producer which polls the database for work and put the job into a BlockingQueue. If there are any worker threads available in the Consumer pool, they can start work on the tasks.

Comment: It's not guarantied, that more threads = better performance...

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc:s for ExecutorService might come in handy here.
Create the work as implementing `Callable`, put them into a collection and use `executorService.invokeAll(<Collection of Callable)`, check for the Futures to complete.
Or just use `executorService.submit(<task>)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to "batch" the records.  Just submit them to the executor service.

If you are concerned that you might overwhelm the JVM's heap by filling the executor service's queue, then create your executor service using (for example) an `ArrayBlockingQueue` as the work queue.  That will cause the executor to reject requests if the work queue gets too long.  Various other strategies are possible.

If you are going to do fancy things with your `ExecutorService`, I recommend that you read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  The API is rich and complex, and warrants thorough reading before you choose a specific implementation approach.

Comment: Configuring the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a Bounded work queue will not result in the `submit()` method blocking until there's room on the queue. It will just throw a `RejectedExecutionException`.

Comment: @bowmore ... yea.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Executor service has a queue to buffer your task when the thread is not available.
You need to write another thread which will submit task periodically to the executor service and also check the completion strategy .i.e if executorservice queue is full required to handle.

Answer (score 1):

While that approach will work, it may still leave some unused computation power, assuming that 16 is the optimal number of threads.

I'd rather use a pull-based approach, in which threads "pull" entries to process:

**Option 1**: Retrieve all records and use a parallel stream:

```
List<Record> allValues = //fetch
allValues.parallelStream().forEach(...do your processing...);

//You can even have a better version that reads data from the result set as needed:
Stream.generate(() -> {
    resultSet.next();
    return rs.getObject(1); //Read/create the value from the record
});
```

**Option 2**: Use a queue of some sort based on all the data retrieved from the DB and then create implementations of callable that processes queue (they loop, each thread remaining busy until the queue is exhausted). You can then use the executor service, launch those tasks:

```
Queue<Object> records; //Create the queue of records
ExecutorService es; // Instantiate the executor service with desired capacity

//Execute the runnable that processes the queue. Only ending when there's nothing on the queue.
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    es.execute(() -> {
        while(!records.isEmpty()) { 
            //You need to handle this as this 
            //check and a poll() call may need to be synced.

            Object next = records.poll();
            //process
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use dedicated ArrayBlockingQueue of size twice as much as the number of available processors (2x16=32, in your case).

A separate thread reads records from database and puts them in the queue. If the queue is full, that thread would wait when a space for the next record become available. If records are processed faster than the reading thread is able to retrieve them from the database, a number of reading threads can be used, all running the same read-put loop.

Consumer threads simply take next records from the queue and process them, in a loop.

Append:
alternative approach is to wrap each record with an object of type `Runnable` (or `Callable`) and submit it to the executor service. One, smaller drawback is that additional wrapper object has to be created. The greater drawback is that the input executor queue may become overloaded. Then, depending of what kind of queue is used, that queue either throw `RejectedExecutionException`, or consume all available core memory. The `ArrayBlockingQueue` in case of overflow simply suspends the producer threads.